# In Access,get the Max time and min time using sql

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, max, min

My table just like this,I want to get the Maxtime and the Mintime, when the user-id is A or B.

```
user_id        time
----------   ----------

A           2016-01-03 23:02:35
A           2016-01-03 23:02:36
A           2016-01-03 23:02:38
B           2016-01-03 22:02:35
B           2016-01-03 22:02:39
```

My code is:

```
 SELECT user_id,Max（time）AS [start], Min(time) AS [end]
 FROM client1
 WHERE user_id is not null
 GROUP BY user_id
 HAVING user_id in (select user_id from client1);
```

I used access as database，like this 
[search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nv2eM.png)

Comment: Your `Having`clause is quite pointless, isn't it?

Comment: You means "HAVING client1.user_id in (select client1.user_id from client1) "

Comment: I meant that you can remove it. It's pointless to let the database check if the `user_id` in the `GROUP BY` is in the list of all `user_id` of the **same** table. That's always the case.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that select below should return desired result:

```
SELECT user_id,Max（time）AS [start], Min(time) AS [end]
 FROM client1
 WHERE user_id IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'Any other value')
 GROUP BY user_id
```

**NOTE:**
 To grub min and max time **for all users** simply remove `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT user_id,Max（time）AS [start], Min(time) AS [end] FROM client1 
    GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: A or B is just a example. There is lots of user_id,such as C,D,E.

Comment: But the number of 'Any other value' is one thousand ？

Comment: where do you getting list of ids ? from another table ?

Comment: No,just in the table，the number of user_id is very large.

Comment: Do you getting that ids number by some condition ?

Comment: then there is no need to add the where clause if you want to get all the user_id s (just remove the filter)